# Problems with nsstring assignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, variable-assignment

I am making an iPhone app where a player uses a car. I want the player to be able to save setting on which car color they want to use. When i read the file that I have made to store the player's car's color my global NSString variable won't change values. here is my code:

```
    NSString *carColor;
    NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"carColor" ofType:@"txt"];
    if(filePath2){
        carColor = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    }
    currentCarImage = [NSString stringWithString:carColor];
```

The variable carColor is assigned the right thing but when I look in the debugger it says that currentCarImage is an empty string. If I were to put this:

```
    currentCarImage = @"greenCar.png";
```

It would work just fine. I even tried this:

```
    NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"carColor" ofType:@"txt"];
    if(filePath2){
        currentCarImage = [NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]];
    }
```

But this also didn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I managed to get it to work in a way but it is still not really satisfactory. I changed my code to this:

```
NSString *carColor;
NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"carColor" ofType:@"txt"];
if(filePath2){
    carColor = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"greenCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"greenCar.png";
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"blueCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"blueCar.png";
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"redCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"redCar.png";
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"purpleCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"pupleCar.png";
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"yellowCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"yellowCar.png";
}
if([carColor isEqualToString:@"turquoiseCar.png"]){
    currentCarImage = @"turquoiseCar.png";
}
```

Comment: There is no point of `stingWithString`, just `currentCarImage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];` is sufficient. Suggestion: take the time to know exactly why you are writing code.

Comment: Tried that as well but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does the value print as an empty string or `(null)`?

Comment: In the xcode debugger it looks like a blank space

Comment: Are you using ARC? Where is currentCarImage defined? And are you checking/reading its value immediately after assignment or sometime later?

Comment: Yes, at the @Implementation of the .h file, checking value immediately

Answer (score 2):

Not shown is hour you "made to store the player's car's color".

Guessing you tried to write it to the app bundle but that is not writable.

Either write to the app's Document directory or more simple use NSUserDefaults.

Example setting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:carColor forKey:@"carColor"];
```

Example retrieving:

```
NSString *carColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"carColor"];
```

Comment: Are you asking how I am storing the player's car's color? If so I am using a text file that is in the app bundle. Like i said the color is being read right the problem is with assigning it to the string.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean the text in the text file is being retrieved fine

Answer (score 0):

You say `carColor` gets assigned to the right thing. So why not bypass `carColor` and directly assign `currentCarImage` to `stringWithContentsOfFile:`?

Comment: Tried that as well but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work